# Dividir vetor de acordo com delimitadores e copiar conteúdo para outras strings em C

Tags: c, string, array

Preciso que a string principal "vetor" seja percorrida até o delimitador '=' e copie os valores anteriores a '=' para "segundo" e os valores posteriores a '=' para "terceiro". Com certeza existe uma maneira mais inteligente de fazer isso, mas como sou iniciante, estou tendo bastantes dificuldades em pensar no código correto para essa exigência.

```
int tam = 256;

char vetor[tam];
char segundo[tam];
char terceiro[tam];
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

fgets(vetor, tam, stdin);

for (i = 0; i < strlen(vetor); i++){
    if (vetor[i] == '='){
        segundo[i] = vetor[i];
    } //continuar percorrendo a string e copiar valores após o delimitador '=' para o vetor "terceiro"
}
```

A intenção é que quando seja inserida a expressão por exemplo: 
9+8i*8-3i=
seja possível tratá-la em diferentes vetores, da seguinte maneira: 
vetor 1: 9
vetor 2: +8i
vetor 3: *8
vetor 4: -3i

Caso haja ideias melhores para o cálculo de uma expressão com números complexos, estou aberto a ideias =)
Ps.1: Tento usar ao máximo as funções nativas do C, tentando recorrer minimamente às funções das bibliotecas externas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma possibilidade seria essa:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){

    int tam = 256;
    char vetor[tam];
    char segundo[tam];
    char terceiro[tam];
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    fgets(vetor, tam, stdin);

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(vetor); i++){
        if (vetor[i] != '='){
            segundo[i] = vetor[i];  // Copia apenas caracteres diferentes de '='
        }
        else{
            break;      // Para o loop caso seja encontrado um '='
        }
    }
    segundo[i] = '\0';  // Coloca o término de string (só pra garantir)

    // Aqui o '=' está na posição i, então temos que começar lendo de i+1

    for (j = i+1; j < strlen(vetor); j++){
        if (vetor[j] != '\0'){
            terceiro[j - i- 1] = vetor[j];
        }
        else{
            break;      // Para o loop caso a string acabe (chegue no '\0')
        }
    }
    terceiro[j - i - 1] = '\0';  // Coloca o término de string (só pra garantir)

    printf("segundo = %s\n", segundo);
    printf("terceiro = %s\n", terceiro);

}
```

Lembrando que caso a string vetor não tenha um '=' no meio o programa não vai funcionar adequadamente.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Fiz dessa maneira e na hora de rodar, os vetores são divididos adequadamente como eu esperava mesmo. O problema é que logo depois dos resultados das 2 strings resultantes, aparecem alguns caracteres estranhos como "ýÿ◄" na linha logo abaixo dos resultados. O que poderia ser?

Comment: Ah sim, no lugar de terceiro[j] = '\0'; Era pra ter sido terceiro[j - i - 1] = '\0'; Já acertei na resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Que tal usar a função `strtok()` da biblioteca padrão `string.h`?

Segue exemplo (testado) de um código similar ao seu:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_TAM   (256)

int main( void )
{
    FILE * pf = NULL;
    char * p = NULL;
    char vet[ MAX_TAM + 1 ] = {0};
    char segundo[ MAX_TAM + 1 ] = {0};
    char terceiro[ MAX_TAM + 1 ] = {0};

    pf = fopen( "input.txt", "r" );

    if(!pf)
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Erro ao abrir arquivo de entrada.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while( fgets( vet, MAX_TAM, pf ) )
    {
        vet[ strcspn( vet, "\n" ) ] = 0;

        p = strtok( vet, "=" );

        if( p )
        {
            strncpy( segundo, p, MAX_TAM );
            p = strtok( NULL, "=" );
            strncpy( terceiro, p, MAX_TAM );

            printf("segundo='%s' terceiro='%s'\n", segundo, terceiro );
        }
    }

    fclose(pf);

    return 0;
}
```

Entrada:

```
fibo=1.6180
e=2.7182
pi=3.1415
sqrt2=1.4142
sqrt3=1.7320
```

Saída:

```
segundo='fibo' terceiro='1.6180'
segundo='e' terceiro='2.7182'
segundo='pi' terceiro='3.1415'
segundo='sqrt2' terceiro='1.4142'
segundo='sqrt3' terceiro='1.7320'
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @lacobus , mas não era exatamente o que eu estava procurando. Consegui a solução para o meu problema colocando ao fim do main a função close(); e adicionando mais uma condição aos laços if, da seguinte maneira: 
    if (vetor[j] != '\0' && vetor[j] != '\n'){ 
acho que o que estava acontecendo é que ao usar fgets, estava sendo computado o acionamento da tecla enter como valor do vetor, alterando a maneira como se executaria o laço. De qualquer maneira, obrigado pela disposição!